# Are there survey papers in theoretical computer science?

Tags: reference-request, survey

Are there conferences or journals where we can publish surveys/literature review papers related to theoretical computer science problems? If provide a list of such conferences and journals.

I know there are many options in applied areas of computer science, but I have not seen this trend in theoretical computer science.

I work in computational algebra and haven't seen any survey papers so far.

Comment: did u google looking for surveys?

Comment: Invited speakers at the various TCS conferences often give surveys about recently active research subareas, so maybe check the invited talks section of your favorite TCS conference. Also, if you have an advisor, the easiest way might be to ask them about surveys on the topics of interest for you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes!

These survey series come to mind:

[Foundations and Trends in TCS](https://www.nowpublishers.com/TCS) (many authors put a free version on their web page)

[Theory of Computing Graduate Surveys](https://theoryofcomputing.org/libfiles/gradsurveys.html)

[SIGACT News Complexity Column](https://dl.acm.org/toc/sigact/2022/53/1#sec2) (and also sometimes other technical columns etc in SIGACT News)

[Bulletin EATCS](https://eatcs.org/index.php/eatcs-bulletin) regularly has surveys and tutorials

To your more specific question, can you be even more specific? "Computational algebra" is a pretty big field. I recall seeing surveys on computational algebraic geometry, computational real algebraic geometry, [computational group theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_group_theory) (several links at that page).

Comment: Just to add to this: there are other FnT series which could be relevant to TCS, e.g., [Communications and Information Theory](https://www.nowpublishers.com/CIT) or [Privacy and Security](https://www.nowpublishers.com/SEC).